Foreground Service works fine on dev build, but in preview build don't
I already have a working fine Foreground Service in an Android app coded on React Native + Expo (49). I use Notifee to create the service and show a notification to do that.
On my dev build, all works fine and the job is done properly. But when I create a preview build to standalone run, the Foreground Service looks like it has started (the notification shows) all the other things seem like it isn't.
Foreground Service just try to connect to a Bluetooth device, if connection is succeded, get the RSSI and calculate an aproxitmated distance to device and disconnects. Next, informs to my server through a REST API. All of this is repeated every 35 seconds.
I added this to AndroidManifest.
<service android:name="app.notifee.core.ForegroundService" android:foregroundServiceType="location|dataSync" android:directBootAware="true" />

and this permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC" />  

But service looks like doesn't started because my backend server don't get called by API :\
What is the difference between a dev and a pre/prod build in this theme? Am I losing some fact about that?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

"all the other things seem like it isn't" Which things, exactly?  It sounds like there's a bug in your service implementation (wild speculation: some issue caused by minification?).  But without the code, it's impossible to say.
